# How to compare two arrays in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, comparison

I have a table named mm_test like follows:-

```
id    educations 
1     3,4,6,8,9
```

**I want to check whether this array contain (4,6)**. How to check this using mysql query. Mysql 'IN' command is not working for me.

I put the query like this...

```
select * from mm_test where educations IN (4,6);
```

But this query returned empty result. Please any one help me.

Comment: Don't use SQL for this. Just store the data in a flat file and use your preferred coding language.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()` and `mysqli_num_rows()` would work beautifully. Which API are you using to connect with?

Comment: *"But this query returned empty result. Please any one help me."* - Show your full code and the API you are using to connect to your database with. Otherwise, I'm not going to put in a *working* answer from my own test. *Good luck*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(4, educations) > 0 and
      find_in_set(6, educations) > 0
```

However, this is generally inefficient.  The problem is your data structure.  You should be using a junction table with one column for each education, instead of storing a list of integers in a highly-inappropriate data structure -- a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think find_in_set will check for only one number in the array. I know the table structure is not proper, but I need like this to avoid  join queries

Comment: @RakhiVijayan . . . That's why there are two conditions.  You should fix the data structure, if you have any influence over that.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `find_in_set(educations,4)` etc. ? As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the order in the answer is right - *needle (integer), haystack(educations)*

Comment: @JayBlanchard I always thought it was the other way around.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if it were PHP it might have been! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this [FIND_IN_SET Manual](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

```
SELECT * 
FROM mm_test 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(4, educations) > 0 
AND FIND_IN_SET(6, educations) > 0;
```